# Unable to open .java files in neatbeans

Tags: netbeans

[image]I was trying to open my project. But when I open a project made in java it doesnot shows me .java files and I was unable to open the files. Please help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Do the files actually exist in hard drive?

Comment: Could you send a screenshut from your project browser tree?

Comment: [Check netbeans docs how to import a project](https://netbeans.org/kb/73/java/project-setup.html?print=yes#projects-importing)

Comment: @Blip Yes, files exit in the folder

Comment: @LaszloLugosi Added the screenshot

Comment: @charu, are you trying to open a ".java" file? or a netbeans project file?

if you are just trying to open .java .. I think you can just drag on the IDE from directory browser  -- to open a netbeans project.. you might have to create/import a project that will create netbeans project files and then you can see it in this dialog..

Comment: @Sendi_t I am unabke to open my project when I try to open nothing is shown to me. Please help me to do run the project.

Answer (score 0):

There are many IDE what help your daily work, one of that is the Netbeans. All of the IDEs have own project files (and structure) to describe the project (source directory, libraries, running properties, etc). So, when you want to open a project, you assumed that there is in the same IDE (project). If not, you need to import the project.

This is a little bit confusing first time, I agree. ;)

EDIT: It seems you try to open project from a subdirectory. The Netbeans holds project files in a nbproject directory. Try to locate that folder.

Comment: IDE is same the project was made in neatbeans itself but don't know how to setup the project again here in new neatbeans